# Stuck in the Chancel

Tags: amnesia-the-dark-descent

I've got the orb pieces, put them in the pedestal (with the tar), but I don't know what to do with the bone, the jar with the string attached to it, or how to create  "Weyer's Tonic".

Answer (score 2):

**You have to go to the Laboratory in order to create Weyer's Tonic**.
In order to get access to it, you have to have obtained the six orbs (like you have), after which you'll have to get captured in the Chancel. Only then,

> upon your subsequent escape from the Cells and
>   flight from the Shadow, the quakes will cause parts of the castle to
>   collapse, making the Laboratory accessible.

Once you're in the laboratory, you'll find all the equipment you need to create the tonic using the following steps:

> - boil the blood on the burner to extract the Vitae;
> - place the jar under the vice,
> - put the poison gland in the vice and crank it until it is squeezed into
>     the jar [in no particular order].
> - Finally, put the jar under the contraption on the center
>     table, and place the Tampter-covered bone inside of the contraption. This will steam the > bone and put the Tampter in the mixture.
>
> The potion is now complete and ready to be used.

<sup>[source](https://amnesia.fandom.com/wiki/Weyer%27s_Tonic)</sup>